# I want authors to be able to edit some items on the site using REST api

Tags: rest, ajax, update-items

I am new at using REST api and fairly new to sharepoint. I got assigned a project to design a home page, which I already did and my boss wants the authors to be able to edit some of the fields on the site.

I believe this was done in sharepoint 2010 via fields or something like that.
I have been reading and doing research and found this can be done with the REST api using an ajax call which I am including below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var ajaxurl = $(this).data\
     ("http://bc- 
     net/Sandbox/juandev/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Qlinks')/items");

             $.ajax({
                url: ajaxurl,
                type: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                },
                 success: function(data){
                    var items = data.d.results;
                    for (i = 0; i < items.length; i++){

                    message += items[i].Date_x0020_of_x0020_Event + items[i].Column2 + ' <br />';                             
                    console.log(items[i].Title);

                    };

                   console.log('success');              
                },
                error: function(error){
                    alert(JSON.stringify(error));
                }
                });


 });


 //]]></script>
```

I am not too sure how to do this so if you guys can help me, it would be appreciated.
Thanks